# Выборка из таблицы с 2 миллионами записей

Tags: mysqli, search, select, mysql

Таблица MySQL -- 2 миллиона строк. Поиск по текстовым полям типа

```
WHERE field LIKE '%word%'
```

длится вечно. Поиск при LIMIT > 3000 также прерывается после 30 секунд и результатов не даёт.

Как можно достать как минимум 20 тысяч записей за один запрос, чтобы он выполнился меньше, чем за 30 секунд?

Comment: Поиск по id c limit? Очень странный запрос. А у вас индекс создан по полю field?

Comment: по моему опыту на myisam like работает быстрее, чем innodb.

Но при таком количестве лучше делать нормальный полнотекстный поиск (например sphinx).

Comment: согласен с предыдущими комментами... sphinx, elasticSearch... туда смотреть надо... like на большом количестве записей плохая затея, дорого обойдется

Comment: id - дополнительный, автоинкремента нет

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум по `field` должен быть построен полнотекстовый индекс. А вообще, как тут уже говорили, стоит использовать sphinx или ещё какой-то специализированный инструмент для полнотекстового поиска если запрос должен отрабатывать быстро.